# React Native app is showing incorrect app in simulator

Tags: react-native

I have this very strange problem when trying to launch a newly created application in the iOS simulator.

I created a brand new project and launched it using `react-native run-ios`. When it loads I click the apps icon and launch. Upon loading it seems to have loaded either an incorrect version of the app, or it's missing the JavaScript that populates the app.

I can't seem to solve the issue. I've done a clean, and rebuild. I've reset the simulator settings. I have the packager running. I've even rebooted the machine as a last ditch attempt.

There's no errors appearing. I'm struggling to figure out what's going on.

Here's an image ... as you can see the content on the loaded app isn't even in the source code.

[image]
Any ideas what's going on?

**Edit**

Even with the packager running I can not access the JS file. Trying to do the following for example:

```
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle
```

... Shows `This site can not be reached`

I've tried running `react-native --port=9990`. It starts, with no errors but I still can't load `http://localhost:9990`.

Comment: Close all your terminal instance and try once..

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't work. I'm getting a step closer as I can now see the packaging server when navigating in the browser. It's just not pulling the JS bundle when loading in the simulator. I'm doing some testing with wireshark to see what's going on. I can see the request being made from the app for the bundle. I should probably submit another question as the question has changed, but I'll try solve the issue before doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I already figured it out, the problem was a process running in the background from the previous app that wasn't allowing the emulator to run the current app.

This is what I did (Linux)

```
lsof -i :8081
```

And killed all the emulator and debugger process I found with

```
kill -9 ID_OF_THE_PROCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @Luis González has suggested above. On top of it, please you need to kill the node process which is binding this thread. Hence, the following steps can be followed:

```
kill -9 <PROCESS_ID_OF_LOCALHOST_OR_DOMAIN_HOST>
kill -9 <PROCESS_ID_OF_TCP_LISTENER>
```

> In my case it was the following:

```
PROJECTA 16901 dilipkosuri   10u  IPv6 0xebee3sssfsfa7cd5d      0t0  TCP localhost:61383->localhost:XXXX (ESTABLISHED)
PROJECTA 16901 dilipkosuri   12u  IPv6 0xebee3sssfsfa7cd5d      0t0  TCP localhost:61383->XXXX (ESTABLISHED)
node      95069 dilipkosuri   17u  IPv6 0xebee67dsdsdf7c1dd      0t0  TCP localhost:XXXX->localhost:61383 (ESTABLISHED)
node      95069 dilipkosuri   20u  IPv6 0xebee67f44dwse5b3d      0t0  TCP *:XXXX (LISTEN)
```

> So had run the below commands to fix the issue.

```
kill -9 16901
kill -9 95069
```

> Alternatively, the following would suffice...

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that two different apps share the same bundle ID and hence its opening the first installed project with that bundle id